# CocoaPods Installation Failure (Unable to resolve dependencies)

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, rubygems, cocoapods

I have a problem while installing CocoaPods on MacOS X 10.3. The first try fails with a DependencyError for nap. I install nap and try again with the same result. Uninstalling and reinstalling doesn't help.

```
andreass-mbp:~ AndreasB$ sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
Password:
andreass-mbp:~ AndreasB$ sudo gem uninstall nap
Successfully uninstalled nap-1.0.0
andreass-mbp:~ AndreasB$ sudo gem install nap
Fetching: nap-1.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed nap-1.0.0
Parsing documentation for nap-1.0.0
Installing ri documentation for nap-1.0.0
1 gem installed
andreass-mbp:~ AndreasB$ sudo gem install cocoapods
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
Unable to resolve dependencies: cocoapods requires nap (~> 0.8); cocoapods-stats requires nap (~> 0.8); cocoapods-core requires nap (~> 0.8.0)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try installing the pre-release version:

```
 sudo gem install cocoapods --pre
```

Comment: Thank you - now I am on 0.39.0.beta.3

Answer (score 1):

My solution is: do

`sudo gem install XXX`

to each of the dependencies that unable to resolve, one by one.

Then `sudo gem install cocoapods`