# Cocoapods install error "Unable to resolve dependencies"

Tags: swift, cocoapods

Please Help, I keep trying to download but same error arrises

This is what I am getting every time I try to download.

Last login: Tue Jul 10 01:08:01 on ttys001

```
Efrats-MacBook-Air:~ mikabitton$ sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Password:

> **ERROR**:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
>       Unable to resolve dependencies: cocoapods requires cocoapods-core (= 1.5.3), cocoapods-deintegrate (< 2.0, >= 1.0.2),
>   cocoapods-downloader (< 2.0, >= 1.2.0), molinillo (~> 0.6.5),
>   xcodeproj (< 2.0, >= 1.5.7) Efrats-MacBook-Air:~ mikabitton$

Comment: Copy/paste error, no screenshots. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32265784/cocoapods-installation-failure-unable-to-resolve-dependencies/32266253 ?

Comment: Have you tried updating cocoapods on your machine?

Comment: andlin: This is what I am recievingLast login: Tue Jul 10 01:09:06 on ttys001
Efrats-MacBook-Air:~ mikabitton$ pod update cocoapods
-bash: pod: command not found
Efrats-MacBook-Air:~ mikabitton$

Answer (score 0):

1. You should install first of all **git** Here is ref.: *https://git-scm.com/downloads*
2. Than you can normally install **sudo gem install cocoapods** etc.